# Присваивание функции внутри объекта к toString() методу

Tags: javascript

Объясните пожалуйста что конкретно происходит в следующем примере:

```
var user = {

    firstName: ‘Alex’,

    toString: function() {
    return ‘User: ’ + this.firstName;
    }
};
```

На сколько я понял это в чем соотносимо с user.toString(), правда в добавок в приведенном примере происходит "модификация" метода. Меняет ли функция возвращенная методом его прототип поведения или как правильно это понимать. Прошу меня поправить и указать истинный путь ( :D ) в местах где я ошибся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `toString()` автоматически вызывается у объектов, когда их надо привести к строковому типу. Например, следующие строки эквивалентны, просто в первой приведение происходит неявно:

```
1 + ""          // => "1"
(1).toString()  // => "1"
```

Так вот, для Ваших собственных объектов Вы можете захотеть определить собственную логику приведения к строковому типу. Если взять объект `user` из Вашего сниппета и попробовать привести его к строковому типу, получится следующее:

```
user.toString()  // => "User: Alex"
user + ''        // => "User: Alex"
```

Comment: спасибо Вам большое за ответ, стало намного понятней :)

Answer (score 1):

В данном коде определен метод `toString`, который будет вызываться при приведении объекта к строке:

```js
var user1 = {
  firstName: 'Alex',
};

document.write("<div>Значение без метода toString: ", user1, "</div>");

var user2 = {
  firstName: 'Alex',

  toString: function() {
    return 'User: ' + this.firstName;
  }
};

document.write("<div>Значение с методом toString: ", user2, "</div>");
```

Comment: @KolesnichenkoDS, опечатка в строке и ошибка в коде - немного разные вещи :)

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение ответ от KolesnichenkoDS в добавок с Вашим развернутом примере с получаемыми результатами помог мне больше разобраться в этом моментею